# Set TI Launchpad Port 2.2 to Capture Interrupt

Tags: embedded, msp430

I would like to use the TI Launchpad Port 2.2 as a capture interrupt, but I must be doing something wrong. How do I set up this pin for a Timer Capture Interrupt?

```
void ConfigureTimerCapture(void){
     // falling edge + CCI1B (P2.2) + Capture Mode + Interrupt
     TA1CCTL1 = CM_2 + SCS + CCIS_1 + CAP + CCIE; 
     TA1CTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2;   // SMCLK + Continuous Mod
}

// Timer1 interrupt service routine
#pragma vector=TIMER1_A1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer1_A1(void)
{
    captureFlag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Which MSP430 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This code configures the timer to capture events from its input, but it does not configure the pin to be routed to the timer input. This must be done with the PxDIR and PxSELx registers; see table 20 of the datasheet.

Comment: You're right but the information about PxSELx is in the slau144j.pdf Users Guide Section 8.2.5 page 329.  Thanks